# Design pattern for chain of transformations to be applied to input

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am developing an application where I have a common problem of taking an input of some type and applying a chain of transformations to it to get an output.

For example, I take an image in the form of `cv::Mat` as input, apply a functor to it to get a bunch of local features in the form of `std::vector<Eigen::VectorXf>` which are then converted to a global descriptor in the form of a single `Eigen::VectorXf`. This is just an example, an actual chain of processing might be a lot longer.

I am trying to come up with a sensible way of representing this. I am currently thinking of a sort of linked list of operations, where each operation calls the next operation unless its `next` field is empty.

Is this the sensible way of going forward? Is there a design pattern that is meant for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The design pattern is called "**Chain of Responsibility**", depending on how you would implement it, what you mentioned about using a linked list is perfectly valid. Try googling it to get a better understanding about it.

Answer (score 0):

[I'm not sure that this applies to you, but this is a little to much to write in a comment.]

A common way of chaining operations in C++ is to actually chain the calls, similar to how the input/output operators can be chained when reading from/writing to a stream.

Lets say you have an object `O` that you can perform operations `a`, `b` and `c` on. Then you could design the operations (functions) to return a reference to `this` (i.e. `return *this`) and you can chain the calls together as

```
O.c().a().b();
```

That is the generic explanation on how to chain operations (function calls) in C++. For your case you probably need to wrap the data in a class that acts as a simple one-layer proxy for the actual operations.

You could do it something like this (example code only, not related to your code):

```
class integer_ops
{
public:
    integer_ops(int start_value = 0) : value(start_value)
    { }

    integer_ops& add(const int v)
    {
        value += v;
        return *this;
    }

    integer_ops& sub(const int v)
    {
        value -= v;
        return *this;
    }

    integer_ops& mul(const int v)
    {
        value *= v;
        return *this;
    }

    integer_ops& div(const int v)
    {
        value /= v;
        return *this;
    }

    int value() const
    {
        return value;
    }

private:
    int value;
};
```

The above class wraps an `int` value and the simple arithmetic operations. It can be used as:

```
int result = integer_ops(5).mul(2).add(10).div(2).sub(2).value();
```

The above code would be equal to

```
int result = (((((5) * 2) + 10) / 2) - 2);
```

with `result` being assigned the integer value `8` in both cases.

I hope you understand the general principle, and can figure out how to apply it to your case.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Joachim. This approach could work quite well for simpler operations, but in most cases the transformations to be applied are quite sizeable and very much disjoint from one another. Housing them all in the same class seems overkill.